# Rotate arrow when hovered over menu link

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to rotate an arrow 90 degrees when I hover over a menu item on my navbar.

The navbar menu when hovered over currently displays a list of sub menus, but I'd like for the arrow to rotate facing down when the submenu is displayed. Submenu hover works as I'd like to right now, but I can only get the arrow to rotate if I hover directly over it. I would like tie the arrow rotation and the submenu display together.

Here's my HTML:

```
<li>
    <a>
        <i class="fa fa-columns" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        Admin
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="administrationsource.php"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Source Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="administrationservice.php"><i class="fa fa-inbox" aria-hidden="true"></i> Service Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="administrationbulkservice.php"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i> Bulk Services</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    nav li:hover > ul
    {
        display: block;
    }

    nav i:hover
    {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
```

I should also note, that the way I have it right now rotates every other menu icon at the moment.
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `nav li:hover > a i { transform: rotate(90deg) }`

Comment: Thank you much appreciated!